# PHP MVC - Is my controller too fat?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I think I put too much code in my controller that was supposed to go in the model.

This is a part of my controller, I'm not gonna paste everything since there is a lot of code.

```
  public function ajaxUsers() {
    if($_GET["action"] == "listUsers") {

        if(!isset($_POST["search"])) {
            $this->_data['Records'] = $this->_model->getUsers();
            $this->_data['Result'] = "OK";
            $this->_data['TotalRecordCount'] = $this->_model->countUsers();
        }
        else {
            foreach($_POST['fields'][0] as $key => $post) {
                if ($post != "" && $key != "reg_date") {
                    $searchTerms = explode(' ', $post);
                    foreach ($searchTerms as $term) {
                        $term = trim($term);
                        if (!empty($term)) {
                            $like[] = $key." LIKE '%".trim($term, '\'')."%'";
                        }
                    }

                }
                else if ($post != "" && $key == "reg_date") {
                    foreach ($post[0] as $key2 => $date) {
                        $datetofrom = strtotime($date);
                        $datetofrom = date('Y-m-d', $datetofrom);
                        if ($date != "" && $key2 == "datefrom") {
                            $like[] = "DATE_FORMAT(".$key.", '%Y-%m-%d') >= '".$datetofrom."'";

                        }
                        if ($date != "" && $key2 == "dateto") {
                            $like[] = "DATE_FORMAT(".$key.", '%Y-%m-%d') <= '".$datetofrom."'";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            ($like) ? $where_clause = "WHERE ". implode(' AND ', $like) : $where_clause = "";   
            $this->_data['Records'] = $this->_model->filterUsers($where_clause);
            $this->_data['Result'] = "OK";
            $this->_data['TotalRecordCount'] = $this->_model->countfilterUsers($where_clause);
        }
        echo json_encode ($this->_data);
    }
}
```

And my model is mostly database queries:

```
  public function getUsers() {
    $data = $this->_db->select("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."users" . $this->_sort);
    return $data;
}

public function countUsers() {
    $data = $this->_db->select("SELECT count(*) as id FROM ".PREFIX."users");
    return $data[0]->id;
}

public function filterUsers($like_clause) {
    $data = $this->_db->select("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."users " .$like_clause. $this->_sort); 
    return $data;
}
public function countFilterUsers($like_clause) {
    $data = $this->_db->select("SELECT count(*) as id FROM ".PREFIX."users ".$like_clause);
    return $data[0]->id;
}
```

Should I moved the foreach loops in the model?

Comment: Looks like you might have too much M in your C. I'd keep all DB references, all SQL code, etc in the model files. Also, `($like) ? $where_clause = "WHERE ". implode(' AND ', $like) : $where_clause = "";` should be `$where_clause = ($like) ? "WHERE ". implode(' AND ', $like) : '';`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'll make the changes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review.

Comment: So every question that has code inside is code review?

Comment: @Speedwheel I think Ian was recommending you post this to [codereview.se].  It might be on-topic there.  I recommend you read [the help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help).  This question might receive better answers there, assuming everything here is working as intended.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I will post there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PHP MVC - Is my controller too fat?

Yeah, especially because it contains business logic, therefore no separation of concerns. And the reason is because you don't implement a model correctly. A model consists of data mappers and domain logic handlers. And things that bring data mappers and domain objects are called **Services**

A model is not a class. Calling model a class is like calling `class MyLiskovSubstitionClass {}`. That's a concept of data asbtraction. Model consists of services.

To implement it correctly, you'd start from writing a mapper:

```
class UserMapper
{
  public function getUsers()
  {
    $data = $this->_db->select("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."users" . $this->_sort);
    return $data;
  }
  // ... The rest what abstracts table access
}
```

And then you'd write a service, which is called `UserManager`

```
final class UserManager
{
      private $userMapper;

      public function __construct($userMapper)
      {
          $this->userMapper = $userMapper;
      }

      public function search(array $input)
      {
           $data = array();

           if (!isset($input["search"])) {

             $data['Records'] = $this->userMapper->getUsers();
             $data['Result'] = "OK";
             $data['TotalRecordCount'] = $this->userMapper->countUsers();

             // Do the rest
           }

           return $data;
      }
}
```

And finally :

```
public function ajaxUsers()
{
    if ($_GET["action"] == "listUsers") { 
      $result = $this->userManager->search($_POST);
      die(jscon_encode($result));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  However, you should find a better name than UserManager: http://www.carlopescio.com/2011/04/your-coding-conventions-are-hurting-you.html

Comment: @Jonah There are a lot of to improve in real-world scenario, that's for sure, but since `UserManager` implies that it can read/write/delete/fetch users and therefore adheres to PoLS, that would be okay in this case.

Comment: @bad_boy thanks for explaining, now I see that I'm using MVP design and not MVC.,

Comment: @Speedwheel Yeah most php developers call MVP as MVC, so in case you hear about MVC chances are they talk about MVP

Comment: @bad_boy you were saying about domain logic handlers, is there any in your example? and isn't domain logic and domain object the same thing?

Comment: @Speedwheel Yeah, that's in theory. For example, if you need to parse some array, to break it down into another one, that would go in domain objects. Domain logic consists of domain objects, it's not the same thing it's part of it.

Comment: @bad_boy Can you link a more complex example of how the model layer works?

Comment: @Speedwheel You can google for Zend Framework 2 modules. There are a lot of real world examples of how it should be. Also If you need a decent framework, ZF2 is a good choice

Comment: Also, image that you write a photo-album. Here a model would consists of `AlbumMapper` and ImageUploader. In this case `ImageUploader` is domain object, and `AlbumMapper` abstracts table access. And the bridge here would `AlbumManager` which brings together `AlbumMapper` and `ImageUploader`. In controller, you'd only pass `$_POST` and `$_FILES` to `AlbumManager`

Comment: So in my first post example I could create another Class that would be the Domain object and move there all the processing of the $_POST array, instead of doing it in the Service (userManager). Right?

Comment: As I said before, anything that is about handling logic which doesn't belong to storage-related logic, goes to domain object. So if you think that doesn't belong to-storage related logic, then yes - you can go ahead and move it there. Also, there's one thing you miss - a component which is called Query Builder (since your queries are dynamic). QB needs to be injected as  dependency to all mappers.